# PersistenceException: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

Tags: java, arraylist, jboss, wildfly, serializable

I have migrated my application from JBOSS 4.2.1 to wildfly 8.1.final, and since then I'm getting some exception for one speciifc action. Following are my Java classes:

```
public class Boli implements Serializable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -8926784294293357769L;
  private String            id;
  private String            description;

  ...}

pulic class MyBean implements Serializable{
  private static final long             serialVersionUID  = -8971724803045133519L;
  @Id
  private int                           agentid;

  @Column(length = 32768)
  private HashMap<String, Serializable> data = 
  new HashMap<String, Serializable>();

  ...}
```

Later within a transaction block I will add an ArrayList of Boli instances to the HashMap field of MyBean. Then whenever I try to save an instance of MyBean I get the following error from wildfly:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:   org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
...

Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Boli from [Module "org.hibernate:main" from local module loader @2471cca7
```

The most astonishing of all is the last error. I don't understand the ClassNotFoundException. The Boli.class is in the deployed jar together with the persistence.xml.
The error doesn't occur if I run the application on JBOSS 4.2.1. So what does wildfly do differently?

Best regards.

Edmond

Comment: Is the Boli class within the jar in a separate package?

Comment: Btw, the last error is the reason for the first one.

Comment: Boli is indeed in a different package than MyBean. It didn't bother JBOSS 4.2.1 though.

Comment: Did you find out on that? Same issue here with Wildfly 8.1 (and hibernate).

Comment: Hi Feder. The problem was that I had added the serialVersionUID field afterwards. The java class had been written without serialVersionUID field at first by a predecessor. So Hibernate could not deserialize instances of the class as the new serialVersionUID value didn't match the one stored in the database. What I did was just roll back the java class to the old version without serialVersionUID field.